# Job queued for execution - botium box

Tags: testing, chatbot

I am using a **tried version of botium**. The solution which was provided previously for such an issue was to check the heartbeat of botium agent.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I am able to connect to the `kori.ai` chatbot and then connect the test set but on running, I get the error:

```
Job queued for execution
```

and on doing the live chat with the bot, I get the error:

```
504 gateway timeout
```

Comment: Two problems - first problem, on the trial server we locked down some features, the Github repository connection is one of those things. Please download and install the Botium Box at your own infrastructure for doing this. The second problem - I confirm that there is this gateway timeout coming back from the Kore.ai servers, this is out of scope for Botium Box. Maybe a temporary outage of the Kore.ai infrastructure.

Comment: okay. understood. thanks for your quick response